# Right click Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, gridview, right-click

I wanted to know if there was a way to select a row and delete on right click from grid view.

I have the delete statement but I just dont have how to select on right click.

I've seen a couple suggestions that say to use mousebuttons.right but that doesnt work for me and errors with the (mousebuttons does not exist in current context)

here is my current fill statement

```
    protected void getGLDepts()
    {
            mpSearch.Focus();
            string[] mpvalue = mpSearch.Text.Split('(',')');
            string coa = "";
            string map = "";
            SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myconn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "USP_GET_GL_BY_DEPT";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DEPTCODE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mpvalue[1].ToString();
            foreach (ListItem item in mpcbl.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    coa += "','" + item.Value;
                }
            }
            if (coa != "") coa = coa.Substring(2, coa.Length - 2) + "'";
            else coa = "''";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@COA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = coa;
            foreach (ListItem item in exceptdefault.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    map += "','" + item.Value;
                }
            }
            if (map != "") map = map.Substring(2, map.Length - 2) + "'";
            else coa = "''";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MAP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = map;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gvMapping.DataSource = ds;
                    gvMapping.DataBind();

                    lblGLDeptData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    lblGLDeptData.Text = " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + " Cost Center/Funds are Mapped to this Department.";
                }
                else
                {
                    gvMapping.DataSource = ds;
                    gvMapping.DataBind();

                    lblGLDeptData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    lblGLDeptData.Text = " No Currently Mapped Cost Centers.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblGLDeptData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblGLDeptData.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                myconn.Close();
                myconn.Dispose();
            }
```

my select row statement

```
    protected void gvSelect(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";           
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvMapping, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);            
        }
    }
```

and my delete statement

```
protected void delSysGLDepts(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbsys.Checked && !cbgl.Checked)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gvMapping.SelectedRow;
            SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myconn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "USP_DELETE_SYS_ROW";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SYSID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[1].Text;

                myconn.Open();
                object count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                myconn.Close();
                myconn.Dispose();

                getSysDepts();
```

Comment: you can add select and delete buttons to your gridview.

Comment: Dont want to use those buttons.

Comment: do you have this bound to a database as well if so I will paste a second example as well under the initial answer

Comment: Yes I Do.  I have an old delete statment i used for it so if there was a way to just select and launch my c# delete function that would be great.

Comment: where was the old delete statement at keep in mind you are trying to trap the rightmouse click event as well as capture the selected row you could just add a Delete button click on it for it's perspective Datagrid Row and add your code to that button event..

Comment: The old delete statement worked off of selecting the row then clicking a delete button else where that launched the c# code that deleted the selected row based on the unique id in that row.  So it was working off of a button click.

Comment: ok you can do something similar I will post an example to see if you can follow it..

Comment: Change `onclick` attribute name to `onContextMenu` and don't forget to register this event for validation

Comment: Yuriy feel free to edit / update the first example if necessary in my answer.. I am trying to get a good grip on helping the OP out.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you both for spending the time to help me and possibly many others out there.  Have yet to find a solution to this online for asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Works well for me:

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onContextMenu ", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()) + "; return false;");
    }
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < GridView1.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(GridView1.UniqueID, "Select$" + index.ToString());
    }

    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: That did not do anything.  With that statement how does it tell it is right click?

Comment: Change `Select' to `Delete` and handle `RowDeleting` event

Comment: Yuriy's example should definitely work for you I also tested his code for confirmation

Comment: @yuriy, when I right click the windows menu is still popping up. Aha

Comment: Also, I am trying to avoid a context menu if that was not clear.  I am just trying to capture the right click event and make that launch my code.